# Pick a number grok

Tags: python-3.x

I'm not sure what I have done wrong this is what I have done

```
number = int(input("Pick a number: "))
if number==42
print("You guessed right!")
```

I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: You're missing a close parenthesis on the first line, a colon on the second line, and an indent on the third.

Answer (score 1):

if this is python then you need to do the following.

```
 number = int(input("Pick a number: "))
 if (number==42) : #dont forget about your : after if, elif, else, for, while, and function calls
     print("You guessed right!")  #need to indent
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to further inprove your code, you can also make it include decimals by using a `float` statement like this:

```
number = float(input("Pick a number: "))
if number == 42:
  print("You guessed right!")
```

I hope this answer helps.